# Storing pictures in Ruby Volt

Tags: ruby, voltrb

I am wondering what the best practice is to store pictures in a model in the Volt framework. Should I just assign it to a model's field or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a component like https://github.com/andrew-carroll/volt-upload

Pictures will be in the database store (currently mongodb) and processed by a TaskHandler

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a good photo upload component right now, but once I get time I'll make one.  You can just create a  and have it hit a HttpController.  The tempfile for the image will be in params._image_field_name  Let me know if you need more help.

Thanks!